# backup and restore UFW configuration

Tags: ufw

I am using ufw since years and I found that ufw does occasionally save its configuration in /etc/ufw directory. One can find these backups in /etc/ufw/ with backup time added.

```
after6.rules
after6.rules.20210709_152715
after.init
after.rules
after.rules.20210709_152715
before6.rules
before6.rules.20210709_152715
before.init
before.rules
before.rules.20210709_152715
user6.rules
user6.rules.20210709_152715
user.rules
user.rules.20210709_152715
```

So my question now is under what condition was this backup made?

Can I trigger such a backup?

Is there a command that will restore such a backup?

Comment: iptables-restore and iptables-save are using a different format to save iptables configuration.

Comment: I just found out that ufw creates such a backup whenever you issue a ufw reset. But I still dont know if there is a command that will restore such a ufw backup.

Comment: man ufw-framework nice description but there is no backup and restore functionality.

Comment: I dont want to rename or read anything. I want to restore the files exactly as they are.

Answer (score 0):

When I did a `ufw reset` a backup was made

[image: result of command ufw reset. It shows all the files it backed up]

In my case only the rule files were backed-up. So if you **only have one backup** you can do this to restore:

```bash
sudo mv /etc/ufw/user.rules{.*,}
sudo mv /etc/ufw/before.rules{.*,}
sudo mv /etc/ufw/after.rules{.*,}
sudo mv /etc/ufw/user6.rules{.*,}
sudo mv /etc/ufw/before6.rules{.*,}
sudo mv /etc/ufw/after6.rules{.*,}
```

If you've got multiple backups, that won't work, you'd have to replace `*` with the corresponding date